# Another way of solving interchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to ask you guys is there a way to build a function like presented under, which will not use id's and won't need any database connection. Why am I asking? I want to make a function which can be called on every desired subpage and will always do the same thing for any type of text or images (but the number  of img's can differ, in ex. on sub page no. 1 i will have 5 lipsticks, on subpage 2 I will have 10 lipsticks) with same class names(or diferent way, don't know ifthere is any). For the time being I have to make new function for every subpage and replace the id, so I will have a very long script with multiplied, same function.

```
var c1 = $('#c1'),
    c2 = $('#c2'),
    img1 = $('#c1p1'),
    img2 = $('#c2p2'),
    active = $('.active-li-img'),
    allImages = $('.cp-img'),
    allColors = $('.cp-img-color');
img1.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c1.fadeIn(0);
});
img2.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c2.fadeIn(0);
});
```

working CodePen:

http://codepen.io/Nikolaus91/pen/3e23c318cf8915708fe1bf2696d88896

Now my code is thaaat long:

```
var c1 = $('#c1'), c2 = $('#c2'), c3 = $('#c3'), c4 = $('#c4'), c5 = $('#c5'), c6 = $('#c6'), c7 = $('#c7'), c8 = $('#c8'), c9 = $('#c9'), c10 = $('#c10'),

    img1 = $('#c1p1'), img2 = $('#c2p2'), img3 = $('#c3p3'), img4 = $('#c4p4'),img5 = $('#c5p5'),img6 = $('#c6p6'),img7 = $('#c7p7'),img8 = $('#c8p8'),img9 = $('#c9p9'),img10 = $('#c10p10'),

    active = $('.active-li-img'),
    allImages = $('.cp-img'),
    allColors = $('.cp-img-color');
img1.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c1.fadeIn(0);
});
img2.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c2.fadeIn(0);
});

img3.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c3.fadeIn(0);
});
img4.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c4.fadeIn(0);
});
img5.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c5.fadeIn(0);
});
img6.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c6.fadeIn(0);
});
img7.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c7.fadeIn(0);
});
img8.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c8.fadeIn(0);
});
img9.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c9.fadeIn(0);
});
img10.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    c10.fadeIn(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change it so that the function is called whenever you click on one of your coloured 'tiles':

```
allColors.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    $('some selector').fadeIn(0);
});
```

The only thing is that your class `cp-img` is on the the `img` element when it would probably be better on the `a`, or you could simply add another class to the `a` and use that selector in the function above.

You could even use `$('div.one-half ul li a')` as the selector as long as the markup is consistent.

The only tricky part is how to find which image needs to be faded in and to do that, the easiest way would be to do the following:

```
var tile_id = $(this).attr('id');
// remove 'p1' from tile id to get image id
var lipstick = tile_id.replace('p1', '');
$('#' + lipstick).fadeIn(0);
```

Again, as long as the `id`s match up this should work, so the whole thing together would be:

```
allColors.click(function (e) {
    allImages.fadeOut(0);
    e.preventDefault();
    allColors.removeClass("active-li-img");
    $(this).addClass("active-li-img");

    var tile_id = $(this).attr('id');
    // remove 'p1' from tile id to get image id
    var lipstick = tile_id.replace('p1', '');
    $('#' + lipstick).fadeIn(0);

});
```

and that should work on all pages regardless of the number of lipsticks you want to use.

**EDIT**

Just noticed the second tile in your example has an `id` of `c2p2` so the above won't work unless it was renamed to `c2p1` and similarly for any other images.

Otherwise, you'd need to figure out how to extract the image `id` from the tile `id` using your preferred naming scheme that you are using and I'm not sure what it is so I'll hold of using it for now.

An alternative would be to use `data` attributes and set the lipstick for each tile in the markup.

e.g.

```
...
<img id="c1p1" data-lipstick="c1" class="cp-img-color active-li-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217235/odcien_31.jpg">
...
<img id="c2p2" data-lipstick="c2" class="cp-img-color" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217235/odcien_32.jpg">
...
```

and then change

```
var tile_id = $(this).attr('id');
// remove 'p1' from tile id to get image id
var lipstick = tile_id.replace('p1', '');
```

to

```
var lipstick = $(this).data('lipstick');
// or $(this).attr('data-lipstick');
```

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, will try to make it work tommorow morning, especially thanks for the tips how to find the image that need to be faded.

Comment: @MikołajK no problem, if you have any issues then update the question and I will try and help or explain any of my suggestions if you're unsure of them.